# Can't use Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

My laptop is Lenovo Legion Y530 (i7 8th - 16GB ram - GTX1050).
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 for it and I was had a trouble with Wi-Fi. When I turn on Ubuntu, Wi-Fi doesn't found any modem.

I tried:

```bsh
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

This outputs:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595 [17aa:b023]
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: e8:6a:64:ce:c7:7c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

Comment: Restart your network manager by " sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager  " -- turn wifi on/off by  " nmcli radio wifi off " and " nmcli radio wifi on "

Comment: That's not working :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop can't use Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243137/laptop-cant-use-wi-fi-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be

Try this, I have a Lenovo 530s with rtl8822be and it works for me. You should be root user.

After install remember to run the command `sudo apt-get update`.

Sometimes you should install twice.

After the first install, if it doesn't work, run the command `./make clean` and install again.

Comment: and do not reboot, shut dwon and start

Comment: Just edit your answer...

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.